# iOS dev: NSDateFormatter problem

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a source @"Tue, 06 Sep 2011 18:32:55 GMT" string and i have to parse it to NSDate.

i've tried in a following way and it works great on a simulators and devices <4 iOS version, but date object becomes nill on iphone 4 device.

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tue, 06 Sep 2011 18:32:55 GMT"];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

i've also tried [df setDateFormat:@"#a, #d #b #Y %H:%M:S #x"], but the problem wasnt solved.

does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that you are not using the expected date format with your iOS4 Device.

Go into your "Settings" -> "General" -> "International" and check that the format used is the same as the other devices.

What I would still find weird though is that you are hard coding the `NSString *dateString` in your example but still it could be the reason.

[image: Date Formats]

Comment: the string is only for example. in my app string comes from nsdictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a setLocale: on the date formatter?